# No XMLHttpRequest 2 progress in Android stock browser

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, android-browser, xmlhttprequest-level2

I have a working file upload form that uses XMLHttpRequest 2 to upload files to Transloadit (a file processing service). The progress events get fired correctly in Firefox and Chrome, both for Desktop and for Android. But the Android (4.0) stock browser does not fire these events, thus my progress bar doesn't work for those users of my site. XHR2 and ProgressEvent are supposedly supported in Android since 3.0, so I don't know what's going on.

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Upload test</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <!-- twitter bootstrap -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var onprogress = function(e)
    {
      var $status = $('.status');
      $status.text('onprogress: ' + (e.loaded / e.total) * 75 + '<br>');

      if (e.lengthComputable) {
        setProgress((e.loaded / e.total) * 75);
      }
    }

    var setProgress = function(percent) {
      percent = percent+'%';
      var $progressBar = $('.progress .bar');
      var $status = $('.status');
      $progressBar.css('width', percent);
      $progressBar.text(percent);
      $status.text(percent);
    };

    var createAttachment = function(file) {
      var params = {"blocking": true,"auth":{"key":"XXX"},"template_id":"XXX"}
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var data = new FormData();

      data.append('params', JSON.stringify(params));
      data.append('attachment[file]', file);

      var evtReceiver = xhr.upload || xhr;
      evtReceiver.addEventListener('progress', onprogress, false);
      xhr.onload = function(e) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(e.target.response)
        $('.image').append($('<img src="' + resp.results['android-thumb'][0].url + '">'))
        setProgress(100);
      };

      xhr.open('POST', 'http://api2.transloadit.com/assemblies', true);
      xhr.send(data);

    };


    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('input[type=file]').on('change', function(event) {
        createAttachment(event.target.files[0]);
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="file" name="my_file">

<div class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="bar" style="width: 0;"></div>
</div>

<div class="status"></div>

<div class="image"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting XMLHttpRequest Progress from PHP Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990933/getting-xmlhttprequest-progress-from-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

The progress event is supported in the Chromium version of the Android Browser:

> Android 4.4 (API level 19) introduces a new version of WebView that is based on Chromium. This change upgrades WebView performance and standards support for HTML5, CSS3, and JavaScript to match the latest web browsers. Any apps using WebView will inherit these upgrades when running on Android 4.4 and higher.

Upgrade to 4.4 to use this API.

**References**

- [Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4 | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

Comment: My phone is already at Android 6.0.1. The problem is not with me, but with the users of my site.